Wireless Adapter not Found Ubuntu 20.04 Kernel 5.15
I am attempting to connect to my network via a 6E AX210 integrated wireless adapter. I am running Ubuntu 20.04 from a bootable external HDD (crucial x8) and have installed iwlwifi-ty-59.601f3a66.0.tgz from intel which is supported on kernel 5.10+ however I am still unable to discover my wireless adapter. I installed the tgz based on the readme file from the zip after downloading it as described from intel. The link is: intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/… In which I used a sudo cp from downloaded directory to lib/firmware/
Any help would be much appreciated. Further troubleshooting attempted includes tethering from phone and attempting sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade. In addition, I have disabled secure boot

Hey Guiverc, thank you for the response. I installed it based on the readme file from the zip after downloading it as described from intel. The link is: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html   Essentially its a sudo cp from downloaded directory to lib/firmware/

Hello Guiverc, I have added more information to the original post. I appreciate your feedback and will attempt to add photos soon to further aid in this issue.

Does this answer your question? Ubuntu 20.04 LTS driver Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX210 160MHz

Try a more recent version of Ubuntu and it should work

Hello moo, thank you for your response. I am trying to stick with Ubuntu 20.04 due to this being what ROS Noetic supports. In the link you provided it still seems OP has an issue as the solution is marked with 'Keep in mind that I've decided to wait and rather used an external Wifi-adapter, Bluetooth transmitter, duo to possible brakes of a system.' As mentioned I am on kernel 5.15 which is 5.10+ and theoretically should be compatible with AX210

You might need to buy yourself an external USB WiFi adaptor if those are your requirements.
